# What are these wooden posts ringed with copper tubes for?

Tags: identification

My friends recently moved into a new house and found these wooden posts in the garden.  In a roughly triangular formation, each is ringed by vertical copper(?) tubes, maybe 1cm wide.  We assume that they supported something but can't figure out what.  We thought perhaps it was for climbing plants, but there are much simpler options for that and the layout is weird.  The estate agent didn't know what they were and my friends aren't in contact with the previous owners.

Two extra facts that may or may not be relevant - extensive work has been done to the garden but we don't know the timeline, so it's possible the wooden fence and paved area weren't there when the posts were added.  Finally, the flower bed in the background was once a sandpit, which suggests that the garden has been modified for children at some point.

*Edit: added some new photos, including a close-up top-down view.  The pipes are nailed to the posts...*

[image: Wooden posts ringed with metal tubes]

[image: Top down view]

[image: Width across post]

[image: Vertical height]

Comment: Maybe some kind of pest control? Are there pest animals in the garden? Or do they make a whistling sound with the wind?

Comment: That's an angle we hadn't considered.  They didn't make any noticeable noise, but it hasn't been particularly windy.  The house is part of a small hamlet surrounded by fields, so it's possible there would be pests in the area

Comment: My guess is that there was a structure built on top of the three "legs." Whether it was a barbeque or some sort of kid's toy is hard to tell, though.

Comment: This might be the most intriguing post ever; kinda like watching LOST.  I SO hope we get to know the answer to this one!

Comment: Are the copper pipes touching the wooden posts or is there a gap?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they were touching, but I'll get back out there and take a top-down photo from one of the posts.  I didn't think to check if the tubes were clear all the way down, or how they were affixed to the posts (I thought nails at the time, but zooming in on the photo those silver blobs don't actually look very nail-head like)

Comment: Such tubes make me thinking it was some easy to install stuffs which was fixed with the lateral tubes. It seems there is nothing that go underground (e.g. some aeration, e.g. for a garden water tank. It is not very English manner, but ask neighbor, they saw, they know.

Comment: I was thinking they are meant for a ring toss game. The copper pipes might protect the posts and give a nice ringing sound when struck.

Comment: Launching bottle rockets? It might be art.

Comment: did the previous owner keep bees, or something: https://www.beesource.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-195827.html

Comment: I've never seen a beehive balanced on a single post like that, but I guess they could have been supports for a table top that a hive sat on.  I'll ask my friends to check with their new neighbours

Comment: My best guess is that these were foundations for three separate trellises.

Answer (score 2):

could it be a wind organ

https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=wind+organ&qpvt=wind+organ&FORM=VDRE

i built some using discarded 2L plastic pop bottles.